# How to install plugins on a per-site basis on a Multisite network?

Tags: wordpress, installation

Is it possible to install and activate plugins on a per-site basis for a WP Multisite setup?
I am creating a "Proofs" network for my clients where I can easily create new sites to show mockups, etc. to the clients.
Some clients require a ton more plugins than others, and I am hoping to keep things better organized.

Basically, I don't want my "Network Plugins" to be convoluted with a ton of plugins that I have to filter through when trying to activate on individual sites.

Is it possible to set it up so that **I can actually INSTALL AND ACTIVATE plugins on each individual site**, NOT from the Network Admin?

Comment: Installation is only allowed in network admin: Plugins can contain code to access DB-data and files other sites in the same network; to prevent this security issue, only network admins can install plugins and themes. I.e. they need to validate that the installed code is network-save

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the **install** part, no, it's not possible. Installation can only be done in the Network panel. Am not finding an official quote, but I'm pretty sure that this is a *no-go*. But here a couple of places in the core where we can see it: [[1]](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/plugins.php#L411) and [[2]](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/plugin-install.php#L18).

From the e-book [Multisite 101](http://halfelf.org/ebooks/wordpress-multisite-101/), there are this suggestions:

- [Exclude Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exclude-plugins/)

  > Exclude plugins from appearing in plugins menu for normal user in WordPress multisite.
- [Restrict Multisite Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/restrict-multisite-plugins/)

  > Provides an interface similar to how the ‘themes’ section looks.
- [Multisite Plugin Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-plugin-manager/)

  > Allows you to manage plugin activation.

I just knew MPM, and with it, you can set 3 states for plugins: hidden, visible and active on blog creation. But it cannot be used to enable plugins on a per-site basis, like WordPress offers as default for Themes.

[image: multisite extended plugin management]

The current plugin version is displaying a couple of notices: one `undefined variable` and one deprecated function. But those are minor and easily fixed.
I've also seen that it is prepared to deal with "premium" plugins, using a third-party add-on or plugin. This can be useful for custom tweaks.

None of the plugins in the list has been updated recently, not necessarily bad, but *caveat emptor*.

I have [one plugin that works on the Network screen](https://github.com/brasofilo/Network-Deactivated-but-Active-Elsewhere) to show which plugin is active where, as this info is not available in the system.

Comment: MPM has been last updated on 2014-4-29 which makes it the best updated of this trio. The other two are two years old.

Answer (score 1):

B/c all of the sites use the same filesystem folder for plugins, I don't think it is possible it install plugins site by site within a multisite.  To make you're life easier, I'd take a look at backup buddy or ns cloner. Both of those make it really easy to clone one site to another in multisite.  I prefer ns cloner, but that isn't to say I know of anything wrong with backup buddy.

If those don't help and you're comfortable in sql, you can look at copying the row in wp_option_x where option_name = "active_plugins" from site you wish to copy to the new one.  That will be a shortcut to activate the plugins on a new site.

Hope that helps.